# Sound Cloud Custom Player not playing

Tags: audio, streaming, audio-streaming, soundcloud

I'm trying to setup an example Sound Cloud player by following the directions [here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player#). I end up with an index.html page that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Sample SC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sc-player-standard.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/soundcloud.player.api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sc-player.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://soundcloud.com/matas" class="sc-player">My latest tracks</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I load the page, everything appears correct and looks functional (ie: you can select tracks, and clicking the 'play' icon turns it into a 'pause' icon, I can see cover art), but no audio plays and the elapsed time for the track never starts. I'm just looking at the page on my local machine through a python server. Is there anything else I should be doing?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using? I copied and pasted your code and tested in Safari, Firefox and Chrome on Mac OS X and Safari on iOS. Try this version and see if it works for you:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14333604/demos/custom-player/index.html

If that works, comment and I'll edit my answer with some other ideas about debugging.

Comment: Paul, that link behaved the same way as the original code/question when using chromium on linux, but worked as expected when using firefox on linux. So it may be a browser issue. Thanks for helping me sort that out. Any ideas for debugging?